# Removing everything except capital letters using replace

Tags: javascript, regex

Yeah, I'm trying to remove everything except the capital letters, though it doesn't really seem to go well.

I used the following code,

```
String.replace(/(?![A-Z])./, '');
```

It doesn't seem to work properly, while it does work using PHP.

Comment: Note: PHP and JavaScript have different flavors of regex, both of which are expansions on the [formal definition of regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so it isn't necessarily a safe assumption that one language's regex will transfer to another... not to say that this example isn't an overlap between the two

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `global` option at the end of the `regex` - see demo below:

```js
console.log("AkjkljKK".replace(/(?![A-Z])./g, ''));
```

Comment: If you don't use `global` option, only the first character match will be replaced...

Comment: That explained it, does it work the same way in PHP too? I barely every used replacements in strings.

Comment: I'm not aware with how PHP does it, but more or less every language handles it in the same way - with some slight changes in syntax...

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! (:

Answer (score 4):

you can use `[^A-Z]` to remove everything except capital letters. Also use `g` to replace all occurrences and not just the first one.

```js
var str = "sOmeVALUE";

console.log(str.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, ""));
```